# Reduce memory size of my PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, memory

I've just come across the problem of the large memory size of PHP arrays. I'm trying to store a fairly small amount of data per object, in a bunch of small arrays. The storage looks like this.

```
[Stats] => Array
     (
    [Apps] => Array
            (
                [Career] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [4] => 0
                        [5] => 0
                    )

                [Team] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [4] => 0
                        [5] => 0
                    )

                [Season] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [4] => 0
                        [5] => 0
                    )

            )

    [SubApps] => Array
            (
                [Career] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [4] => 0
                        [5] => 0
                    )

                [Team] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [4] => 0
                        [5] => 0
                    )

                [Season] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [4] => 0
                        [5] => 0
                    )

            )
```

I need 20 or more of the middle arrays shown here (e.g 'Apps', 'SubApps' etc). It's an array of arrays of arrays, with the final arrays always being exactly 6 values long.

Since it's just 18 values, I'd assumed that it wasn't much memory, but I've found out that PHP uses about 144 bytes per value, so it's turning out to be huge, especially since I have about 3000 such objects. It's using about 30k per object, just on 20 of these array blocks.

So I'm looking for a memory efficient solution. Since my final array is always 6 values, I'm thinking that maybe I can pack/unpack. I also looked into SplFixedArray but it doesn't suit my needs in some ways and doesn't save much memory. I also want the values to show in a readable format in my database in case I need to edit them manually in the db (one method I tried saved memory but the values were garbled in the db).

UPDATE - Solution. I found a simple solution to this. The arrays are JSON_encode'd for saving to the database. When I load them, they're decoded. Initially I was decoding the whole batch at once, hence the massive memory usage, but the simple solution was to keep them encoded until needed, then decode - process - encode. This way, only one is ever decoded into the array and the rest remain encoded, which appears to use very small amounts of memory.

Comment: I was just reading about that, how much better is it? Also I spoke to my web host and they've said that they currently have no plans to upgrade to 7, although I assume they will eventually.

Comment: Are you reaching the `memory_limit` or even close (128m).  If not I don't think you need to worry all that much.

Comment: I'm reaching the 32mb memory limit on XAMPP. afaik, that can be increased to 128M and I think I won't get near that. Also it's set at 128M on my host so maybe, as you say, it's not a huge problem. But I still feel a bit keen to reduce the size here.

Comment: So 2.5x less in 7? tbh, with 7 and boosting Xampp up to 128M, I should be fairly clear?

Comment: How big can the numbers in the arrays of 6 numbers be?

Comment: They'll need to be 32 bit, since they will definitely go over 65,536 but will never go over more than a few million (certainly nowhere near the 4 billion + of a 32 bit number). That's a good point, I assume they're 64 bit by default, so is there a simple way to reduce them to 32 bit when they're created?

Comment: lots of arrays like that suggest to me you should be making better use of a data base.

Comment: Why do you need 3,000 objects in memory at once? Perhaps you can reclaim mem space by thinking along those lines

Comment: @BeetleJuice  You're right and a perfect solution presented itself. The arrays are json encoded for the db, then decoded for processing. I realised that I could decode - process - encode so that only 1 or 2 are ever decoded at the same time. In their encoded form, they appear to take up almost no room, so the problem is solved :)  Not sure if I should update my answer with this?

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not reduce the amount of data in the array, if your array is mostly empty or same-value as you have there, why not just export an array like this array( ...  [samevals] = true, [indexes] = 12, [value] = 0)  This way you can iterate over the int instead of parsing the array of same values. It a way to reduce array size and therefore reduce memory use.

Comment: They wont be same-value for long, those are just when I'm creating the array. Later on, they'll be full of different values.